# как открыть файл json если он закодирован в cp1251 или koi8?

Tags: python, python-3.x

как открыть файл json если он закодирован в cp1251 или koi8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('some.json', encoding='cp1251') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)
```